# ValueError: axes don't match array

Tags: python, numpy, conv-neural-network, transpose

I am trying to do tanspose but after this I have error ValueError: axes don't match array

```
frames = np.array([video])

frames = np.expand_dims(frames, axis=1)

frames  = frames.transpose(0,3, 2, 1)

preds = model.predict(frames)
```

Comment: Your question includes to less informations to solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is the shape of `frames`?

Answer (score 0):

i make some of my own opinions.Like the buddies upstairs said,lack of informations to solve the problem.
I read your code.You should know 
`frames = np.expand_dims(frames, axis=1)`means.it is to add a dimension to the "axis = 1" dimension,and the original "dimension" is pushed to the right.Next, `frames  = frames.transpose(0,3, 2, 1)` Transform the 1st and 3rd axes,and the rest remains unchanged.But look at it, the total dimension is 4.You need to pay attention to whether it is equal to 4 after adding a dimension.